# loginwithpassword seems to be conflicting with router

Tags: routes, meteor, meteorite

I have a pretty standard filter that checks if you're logged in:

```
requireLogin: function(page) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        return page;
    }   else if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        return 'loading';
    }   else {
        return 'login';
    }

}
```

Now when I go to a page that requires login, I get the login template as expected with the url unchanged. However, if I just try to log in with loginwithpassword, its loggingin() for a bit, and then returns to the login template as if nothing's happened (the callback function never seems to be called). Now if I just log in from the /login url with the same template, logs in fine.

log in code:

```
'click .userlogin':function(e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(
        {email: tmpl.find("#emailInput").value},
        tmpl.find("#passInput").value,
        function(err){
           if (err) {
                // handle error
                Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
                Session.set("showErrorMessage", true);
            } else {
                // show an alert
                Meteor.Router.to('/profile');
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609109/meteor-login-not-working-on-mobile

Not sure whats the cause... Any progress?

Comment: check out around line 21: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js

Comment: https://github.com/ccorcos/meteorPasswordMobileError