# Meteor login not working on mobile

Tags: meteor, mobile-safari

I am working on a simple mobile web app and I am having trouble logging in...

I followed this little sample on making a custom login: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor

Nothing too tricky here.

So I run my meteor server locally. On my computer, through the browser, I can log in and create accounts -- no problem.

When I go to my local IP from my iPhone, the website successfully loads but for some reason I am not able to login or create accounts.

I have noticed that for `Meteor.loginWithPassword` and `Meteor.createUser`, the callback function NEVER gets called. I have `{{loggingIn}}` rendering a loading screen and the loading screen is only there for a fraction of a second before the form is reloaded. No errors are thrown (validation passes and the callback function doesnt fail).

Out of suspicion, I deployed the app and tried accessing the deployed website from my phone and the same issue persists...

Any ideas what I cannot log in or create accounts on my iPhone, but I can on my computer? Maybe its a cookies thing? Any ways of solving this?

Thanks a lot,

Chet

Edit:

This works on both my desktop browser and iPhone simulator. Just not my iPhone. Could it just be a local network issue? -- No, even if I deploy the website, I have the same issues...

Also, check out my github post about recreating the issue:
https://github.com/ccorcos/meteorPasswordMobileError

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you are running the same version of iOS on all the devices you are testing on.  I have seen iOS 7 misbehave when using Meteor apps. iOS 6 works just fine.

Comment: works on chrome on iOS 7. still waiting to check Safari iOS 6